# К каким отрицательным последствиям может привести использование верхнего регистра при именовании файлов в Node.js-приложении?

Tags: node.js

Из [перевода](https://habr.com/company/Voximplant/blog/277707/) статьи "[10 Habits of a Happy Node Hacker](https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016)":

> Несмотря на то, что OSX и Windows будут считать файлы myclass.js и
>   MyClass.js одним и тем же файлом, Linux так считать не будет. Если вы
>   хотите писать кросс-платформенный код, вам необходимо именовать файлы
>   в том же регистре, который вы используете для require.

Если я всё понял правильно, по проблема возникнет только в том случае, если в одной директории есть файлы `myclass.js` и `MyClass.js`. Но такой случай на практике - редкость (тем более из выше сказанного следует, что если разработка ведётся НЕ на линуксе, то о подобном именовании двух файлов не может быть и речи), а если и возникнет, то можно просто назвать второй файл по-другому, и всё. А если так, то приведённое выше совет можно полноценно заменить советом "Не именуйте файлы одинаковым набором символов, различающихся лишь регистром".

К каким ещё проблемам  может привести использование верхнего регистра в nodejs-приложениях?

Comment: `require myclass.js` файла MyClass.js под виндой не вызовет проблем, а вот линукс начнёт материться. Всегда следи за регистром, на какой бы ОС не велась разработка

Comment: @dev_null, ну я просто напишу `require('MyClass.js')` и всё, разве это не странно, что имя файла в - одном регистре, а requre - от другого регистра?

Comment: Об этом и говорится в алерте, регистр имеет значение. Просто сменить единственный `require` это хорошо, а вот на более менее крупном приложении, с сотней подключаемых файлов, придётся повозится

Comment: @dev_null, в общем, чтобы прийти к какому-то логическому заключению: я правильно понял, что если мы пишем приложение с нуля, при этом имена файлов (модулей) и аргументов `require()` совпадают вплоть до регистра, то мы можем спокойно использовать верхний регистр, при этом всё будет кросплатформенно работать?

Comment: Да, достаточно соблюдать регистр в именах и `require`